# Django count and store values in models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have multiple Models which look like this:

```
class Classes(models.Model):
User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
A1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
B1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
etc
A2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
B2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
etc
A3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
B3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
etc
A4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
B4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
etc
Sum_of_1 = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
Sum_of__2 = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
Sum_of__3 = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
Sum_of__4 = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True)
```

its a bit bigger, anyways, I want A and B etc sum together and save the result in sum of 1 etc. First I thought that a form would be good for that but the sum fields should always have the sum they never should be updated so then I thought rewriting the save method in models, I got this but it just gives me an recursion error I know why but have no solution for that

```
super().save(*args, **kwargs)
if self.Sum_of__1 or self.Sum_of__2 or self.Sum_of__3 or self.Sum_of__4 is None:
self.Sum_of__1 = self.A1 + self.B1 + self.C1 + self.D1 + self.E1
self.Sum_of__2 = self.A2 + self.B2 + self.C2 + self.D2 + self.E2
self.Sum_of__3 = self.A3 + self.B3 + self.C3 + self.D3 + self.E3
self.Sum_of__4 = self.A4 + self.B4 + self.C4 + self.D4 + self.E4
self.save()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please *don't* store data duplication (or aggregates of data). It is very hard to keep these in sync effectively (imagine that you later update `B1`, then you will need to update `Sum_of__1` as well).

Comment: I couldve guessed that this is absolute the wrong way. But I cant find anything. It would be actually enough to know how to look for it :D. The thought behind this is, I want to store the sum bc I need to use it later for other calculations, and in the perfect world this sum is always the sum of the fields, so if someone updates b1 without a1 the sum updates thats all I need

Comment: why not use a `@property` that calculates the `sum_of_1` if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a call to the `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` *after* updating the sums, so:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.Sum_of_1 is None or self.Sum_of_2 is None or self.Sum_of_3 is None or self.Sum_of_4 is None:
        self.Sum_of_1 = self.A1 + self.B1 + self.C1 + self.D1 + self.E1
        self.Sum_of_2 = self.A2 + self.B2 + self.C2 + self.D2 + self.E2
        self.Sum_of_3 = self.A3 + self.B3 + self.C3 + self.D3 + self.E3
        self.Sum_of_4 = self.A4 + self.B4 + self.C4 + self.D4 + self.E4
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it is a *really* bad idea to store aggregates: it introduces a form of data duplication, and will result in a *lot* of trouble to keep the values in sync with each other: if you later change for example `B1`, you will need to updater `Sum_of_1` as well. While that may look easy, there are several ways through the ORM, or through raw database queries, or other applications, that will circumvent the `.save()` call, and thus eventually the data will no longer be synced correctly. It might be better to just define a property, like:

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MDOEL,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    A1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    B1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # etc.
    A2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    B2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # etc.
    A3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    B3 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # etc.
    A4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    B4 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # etc.
    
    @property
    def sum_of_1(self):
        return self.A1 + self.B1 + self.C1 + self.D1 + self.E1
    
    @property
    def sum_of_1(self):
        return self.A1 + self.B1 + self.C1 + self.D1 + self.E1
    
    @property
    def sum_of_2(self):
        return self.A2 + self.B2 + self.C2 + self.D2 + self.E2
    
    @property
    def sum_of_3(self):
        return self.A3 + self.B3 + self.C3 + self.D3 + self.E3
    
    @property
    def sum_of_4(self):
        return self.A4 + self.B4 + self.C4 + self.D4 + self.E4
```

Comment: I really want good practise for this solution. how should I store the aggregated data ? But holy cow this works amazing!!!

Comment: @random1312: you should *not* store it, just calculate it when needed, with a `@property`. See edit.

Comment: YOOOOO You are the MAN, but how can I show it to the user in the templates and also use the sum to calculate with other sum ? is it also possiboe without storing it ?

Comment: @random1312: just as any field, so `{{ myobject.sum_of_1 }}`.

Comment: thank you so much!! can I also count that in template ? like myobject.sum_of_1 + and so on ?